# cakephp 3 globule function for model(Table)

Tags: model, cakephp-3.0

In cakephp 3 I have class of demo

```
class DemosTable extends Table {

}
```

Like that so I want to create one function as globally for all Table class so how can I define it?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a behavior and use it where needed instead of putting it in a super model class like appModel in 2.x.

Look [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#behaviors) for the documentation about behaviors

Comment: but i am use cakephp 3 dear

i want to create globule function for all Table in model,
in older version AppModel class is use to define globule function